# Should I namespace my angular directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

AngularJS defines a `ng` prefix for its directives like `ng-repeat`. When I create my own directives is it a best practice to prefix them?

For instance which is better?

```
<chat></chat>
or
<myown-chat></myown-chat>
```

Where `myown` is my website specific namespace.

**[UPDATE]**

Now the AngularJS guide suggests to namespace directives https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives

Comment: Now the Angular documentation suggests to namespace your directives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do. I think it is a good practice, especially as you use modules from others that may include additional directives, and things get more confused, and create some small chance of name collision.

If your directives are namespaced, then anyone who goes to read or edit the code will know when to look for the directives in the app's own codebase, and not from some 3rd party.

The popular angular-ui project namespaces all their directives, as does angularstrap.

I think of it as a generally adopted standard; a common and good practice.

Comment: Thanks. And how do people namespace their directives? Two characters like Angular or more?

Comment: No hard and fast rule, I am generally seeing 2 letters, either following angular's example and using 'ng', or I think a better idea, using their own.